# R repeatedly adding similar column from different data frames into one data frame

Tags: r, for-loop, sapply

I have 10 data sets : prediction1.csv, prediction2.csv, ... and they all have similar columns e.g a, b, c..

I want to add the "a" column from each of the data sets into a combined data frame "evaluating"  and rename them accordingly a1, a2, a3..

What I have tried so far is:

I red in the data sets. this part works fine

```
for(i in 1:10){
  assign(paste("pred.", i, sep = ""), read_csv(paste0("prediction", i, ".csv")))    
}
```

I tried to assign new columns to the "evaluating" data frame, but this does not work, it creates variables `evaluating[a1]` instead of adding a variable to the data frame

```
for(i in 1:10){  
    assign(paste("evaluating[a.", i,"],"), paste0("pred.",i,"$a" )) 
}
```

Comment: Do you want one `a` column or multiple `a` columns, and if the latter, do all data frames have the same number of rows?

Comment: All those 10 data sets are outputs of the model, i.e they have all same column names.  And I am interested of column "a" from each of them and the evaluating data frame has the real values in it. So I want a data frame that has real a, a from df1, a from df2, a from df3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the `a` column of every data.frame you can try:

```
files = paste0("prediction",1:10,".csv")

data = lapply(seq_along(files),function(x) {
    dat = read.csv2(paste0("path/to/file/",files[x]))
    dat = data.frame(dat$a) ; colnames(dat) = paste0("a",x)
    return(dat)
})

do.call(rbind,data)
```

For this approach, all `prediction` data.frames need to have the same amount of rows as well a a column named `a`.

Comment: There is a closing bracket missing in the data=.. I assume it should be after }
However I get a following error:
Error in do.call(rbind, data) : second argument must be a list

Comment: can you share a `dput` of your prediction data.frames?

Comment: I am not sure what the dput is. However, I found I typo I made. However, when fixing it, I got a next error:
Error in names(x) <- value : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]. As the files are in my working directory, I used just read.csv(files[x]) now and don't get issues with data anymore. But I get a new error: 
Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names